# CMD Findstr - Line starting with 13 digits

Tags: regex, findstr

I have multiple lines like this

```
1480438326593   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
```

and I want to parse them with `FINDSTR` function from windows CMD.

My problem now is the arguments don't work, or probably I am doing it wrong, but it should work.

I am using this command `findstr /V /R ^\d{13}` which should use regex and find any digit 13 times at the start of a string.

`findstr /V /R ^\d` this does work as intended if it starts with a digit but the {13} doesn't work - any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To return lines that start with 13 digits use

```
findstr /r ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

If you want to fail (not match) cases where the 13 digits are followed with more digits (i.e. do not match `12345678901234 more text` lines), add `\>` (trailing word boundary) at the end.

The [`findstr` utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb490907.aspx) does not support *proper regex*, only some wildcard patterns, so, there  is no [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) (i.e. `{min,max}`) support, nor shorthand character classes like `\d`.

Here is the table of patterns `findstr` supports:

```
┌───────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Character │ Value                                                           │
├───────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│    .      │ Wildcard: any character                                         │
│    *      │ Repeat: zero or more occurrences of previous character or class │
│    ^      │ Line position: beginning of line                                │
│    $      │ Line position: end of line                                      │
│ [class]   │ Character class: any one character in set                       │
│ [^class]  │ Inverse class: any one character not in set                     │
│   [x-y]   │ Range: any characters within the specified range                │
│   \x      │ Escape: literal use of metacharacter x                          │
│  \<xyz    │ Word position: beginning of word                                │
│   xyz\>   │ Word position: end of word                                      │
└───────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Note that adding `\v` option will reverse the results: you will get all lines that do not start with 13 digits.